# $W^2_0$ Poincaré inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded set. Taking the Hilbert space
$$W^2=\{v\in \mathcal S'(\Omega):\ v\in L^2,\ |\nabla v|\in L^2,\ \|D^2v\|\in L^2\ \}$$
in order to prove an analogue of the Poincaré inequality
$$\exists C:\ \forall v\in ?\subset W^2(\Omega)\qquad \|v\|_{W^2}\le C\|\Delta v\|_{L^2}$$
we have to restrict to a subspace where:

1. the functions take value zero at the boundary?
2. the functions and their normal derivatives take value zero at the boundary?

I would expect the second option, nevertheless, even for $\Omega=(-1,1)$ I cannot find an example of function $v\in W^2(\Omega)$ where the boundary value is zero and
$$\|v\|_{W^2}>>\|v''\|_{L^2}\qquad v(-1)=v(1)=0$$
so I wonder if we can have a control of the norm even in case 1.

Comment: Remark: is is Poincaré, not Poincarè!

Moreover, are you sure of your second equation? It seems you are looking to bound the second derivative by the first derivative here ...

Comment: I mistook the nabla for the delta

Comment: Of course in dimension $1$, $\Delta v = D^2 v$ so the norms are the same, and you will not find any counterexample there ...

Comment: Ok but $\|\cdot \|_{W^2}$ not made by $D^2v$ alone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $u \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)\cap H^{2}(\Omega)$ and let $f=-\Delta{u}$.
Then $u$ is the unique weak solution of $$-\Delta{u}=f $$ on $\Omega$ with zero-boundary conditions on $\partial{\Omega}$ and we can therefore use standard regularity estimates (see Evans Chapter 6 for example) to conclude that $$||u||_{H^{2}} \le C \cdot ||\Delta{u}||_{L^{2}}$$
for some constant $C>0$ that depends only on $\Omega$.

So if $\Omega$ is sufficiently regular, all you need is zero trace!